Angularjs ui-grid data to pdf exporting issue
I developed below UI grid in .net core mvc application, but when export grid data to PDF, footer total is not exporting to PDF document. I Used angularjs 1.8.3 and visual studio 2022.

when export the grid data to pdf, it look like this.

I used a template for total column,
 columnDefs: [
    //////////////////
{
        field: 'GetTotal()', exporterPdfAlign: 'right',
        enableCellEdit: false, 
        width: '15%',
        footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents cellAlignRight gridcell-number-align">Total : {{grid.appScope.netTotal($event, row.entity) | currencyFilter:this}}</div>', 
        cellClass: 'gridcell-number-align',
        name: 'Total',
        cellFilter: 'currencyFilter:this',
        aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum 
    }
    //////////////////////

How can I fix this exporting issue?
